# The calendar for consecutive days has gotten worse

Tags: bug, profile-page

The consecutive day calendar formatting has gotten much worse. The previous version didn't have all this whitespace between cells.

I can't get a screenshot of the old profile page, but if you look at it... it didn't look like this:

[image]

---

Edit, I found these screenshot of the previous calendar:

[image]
[image]

Bug posted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253766/190291

Comment: I agree that this does not look very nice. You should add this (if it's not already) to the master list for new profile feedback: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Comment: @gunr2171 didn't know that page existed, I will add it now